# Git automatically changing file extensions

Tags: linux, windows, git, file-extension

I have a git repo with some fortran source code with the file extension `.for` on windows. This code is compiled and run by a 3rd party software that throws an error if the file extension is not `.for`. A rather annoying feature of this 3rd party software is that, on linux, it requires a `.f` file extension for the same fortran source code files. So when I clone the git repo to a linux system, I have to change the fortran source files to `.f`. How can I configure git to do this automatically, so when I clone to linux, all fortran files have a `.f` file extension and on windows the same files are `.for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a git problem, so the obstacle you found is mainly because you want to use a hammer for the task of a screwdriver.

In your place I would do one of the followings:

- git can handle symbolic links are well, so you can construct a symlink on the the `.for` for every `.f` files (for example: `for x in *.f;do ln -svf ${x%.f}.for $x;done`)
- you can set up hooks for checkouts and commits in `.git` directory which rename the files before/after commit on need. You can set up it so that you will have `.for` on the local repo, but `.f` in the remote.

The first is much simpler, but not really beautiful. The second is very beautiful, but requires tricky scripting, and it would be *unstable* (some tiny problem with the hooking scripts could harm your source). To me, the first is better.